# How to spot equally likely events easily?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Formula of probability of an event $(E)$ such that all sample points of a sample space $(S)$ are equally likely is given by :

$$P(E) = \frac{n(E)}{n(S)}$$

This formula is in general not true as told by my teacher (for example, in experiments involving in-equally likely events) . Now, equally likely events are the events which have same probability of occuring.

It is easy to see through our "common sense" that tossing a fair coins have a set of equally likely events but it gets increasingly difficult for me to identify them in complex questions.

So, isn't all of this just circular ? We need to know whether outcomes are equally likely or not before using formula. But to determine if they are equally likely, we need to first use the formula because because formula is not true in general.

Can you provide me some good ways and techniques through which you identify that outcomes are equally likely or not ?

PS: I am just in high school so a simple and easily understandable answer is appreciated. However, all answers are welcome.

Comment: "We need to know whether outcomes are equally likely or not before using formula." Is wrong. You can use the formula above for $P(E)$ for any two events $E$ and $E'$ whether they are equally likely or not.

Comment: @KurtG. okay. I am actually a newbie in probability so I am afraid that I would make more mistakes if I edit. If you've got the feeling that what I am actually asking,  I would be grateful if you can edit it correctly so that I can get answers. Thanks !

Comment: What does $n$ mean in the formula?

Comment: This won't help. We all learn from our mistakes. Is the case clear now where the formula $P(E)=n(E)/n(S)$ applies to any event? If so you should follow up with specific questions.

Comment: @JMP It means the number of elements. Thanks

Comment: @KurtG.  Okay. I should ask how does it work when I get stuck in a question. Thanks

Comment: If $E$ is $\{heads\}$ and $S$ is $\{heads,tails\}$, how you determine a biased coin?

Comment: Either in a comment or even better in an edit of the question you show specifically what the remaining problem is. Saying that something is increasingly difficult in complex questions does not meet those requirements.

Comment: @JMP If E is {heads} and S is {head,tail} , then how does it mean that coin is biased .

Comment: @KurtG. Ok thanks. I'll edit question soon.

Comment: So each element in $S$ should appear only once?

Comment: @JMP Yes , if die is thrown only once.

Comment: @Kurt: I couldn't understand your first comment. The boy seems to be trying to  write down the classical def of probability. And you must be implying about the empirical definition there when you said, "You can use the formula above for ()
P
(
E
)
 for any two events 
E
 and ′
E
′
 whether they are equally likely or not" . Please ease my heartburn here.

Comment: @FAM I was targeting OP's thinking that this is "just circular". The formula $P(E)=n(E)/n(S)$ holds when each element of $S$ has an equal probability of occurring and they are independently drawn. That's it. Two events $E$ and $E'$ are then equally likely if and only if $P(E)=P(E')$, that is, $n(E)=n(E')$. Nothing here is circular whatsoever. I guess I see now where OP is coming from. To determine in this case if general events $E,E'$ are equally likely we need the condition that singletons are equally likely. The latter does however not need a formula to be probed.

Comment: Plus: equally likely in this case means just having same number of elements. The simplest of all ways of looking at it. No chance that this is circular.

Comment: @An_Elephant . I am with you. BTW I think you are on the right track to ask interesting quetions, namely "what is truly random" ? You may want to read about how Richard von Mises tried to answer this question around 100 years ago, and how Andrei Kolmogorov introduced his axioms to avoid really answering this question. Frequentist / Bayesianism are other buzz words you may want to google and read about.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks sir. I will do my best :)